# pass variable value between html to php (server side code) mail function

Tags: php, email, server-side

I'm trying to create a contact us form in my website (where I want to send the email without opening mail client window) and for that I got to know that I have to use `Server side code` for handling the mail() function this is what I found so far :

My form in html page :

```
<form action="sendmail.php">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" required="">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Email" required="">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" required="">
                        <textarea placeholder="Message" required=""></textarea>
                        <input type="submit" value="SEND">
                    </form>
```

My sendmail.php file (on server side)

```
  <?php
$to      = 'support.@mydomain.com';
$subject = 'the subject'; // here how can i get the subject 
$message = 'hello'; // here how can i get the message 
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" . // here
```

How can I get the the dynamic values??

```
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

So how can I pass the values entered by user on html form as parameter in my php function ??

Update, attempt:

```
$subject = 'echo htmlspecialchars($_P‌​OST['subject']);';
$message = 'echo htmlspecialchars($_P‌​OST['message']);';
$headers = 'From: echo htmlspecialchars($_P‌​OST['email']);' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: webmaster@example.co‌​m' . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(); mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); ?>
```

Error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/a9700859/publi‌​c_html/sendmail.php on line 3

Comment: Do you want the php code to work in html file ?

Comment: no , i want to forward the data which is entered by user , to php function

Comment: `$_GET` & `$_POST`?

Comment: What have you tried? What errors did you get? If no errors displayed please post your PHP error Log. Thank you

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php.

Comment: @MarkTwigg ? for real ?

Comment: yes for real, how can we help if you're not telling us whats gone wrong? There's nothing to fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using the $_POST method.

The HTML page.

```
<form method="POST" action="sendmail.php">
 <input type="text" name="sender_name" placeholder="Name" required="">
 <input type="text" name="sender_email" placeholder="Email" required="">
 <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" required="">
 <textarea placeholder="Message" name="message" required=""></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="send" value="SEND">
</form>
```

Here is your sendmail.php

```
<?php
if($_POST['send'] == 'SEND'){

$to      = 'support.@mydomain.com'; // email where message is sent
$subject = $_POST['subject']; // here how can i get the subject 
$message = $_POST['message']; // here how can i get the message 
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" . // here how can i get the the dynamic values   
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks man its working fine now , appreciate your effort

Comment: hey man @kikuyu1 i'm having problem here can you help out ? `$headers = From: $_POST['sender_email'] . "\r\n" . 
    'Reply-To: $_POST['sender_email'];' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();`  i'm getting error which says `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in your code on line 9`

Comment: `$headers =' From: '  ". $_POST['sender_email‌​']."  . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: " ".$_POST['sender_email‌​']." ; . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();` Learn how to concatenate php in html.

Comment: hey man still getting this error  `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"' in your code on line 9`

Comment: `$headers .= "From: ".$_POST['sender_name​']." <".$_POST['sender_email‌​'].">\r\n"; 
   $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST['sender_email‌​']."\r\n"; $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";` try use this instead